# Typeerror: 'Nonetype' Object is not iterable python

Tags: python, typeerror

I don't know why this code keeps throwing an error. I don't know where I might have been gone possibly wrong? The debugged output is totally correct though.
this code compiles and outputs well if I don't use the functions and the main section.

```
import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys


def climbingLeaderboard(scores, alice):
    for i in range(0,len(alice)):
        nscores = list(set(scores))
        nscores.append(alice[i])
        nscores.sort(reverse = True)
        print(nscores.index(alice[i])+1)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')

    scores_count = int(input())

    scores = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))

    alice_count = int(input())

    alice = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))

    result = climbingLeaderboard(scores, alice)

    fptr.write('\n'.join(map(str, result)))
    fptr.write('\n')

    fptr.close()
```

Comment: Take a look at the value of `result`...

Comment: The debugged output is totally correct though. this code compiles and outputs well if I don't use the functions and the main section and never returns None

Answer (score 0):

Your `climbingLeaderboard` function should return a value. You should also initialize the `nscores` list and sort it outside the `for` loop:

```
def climbingLeaderboard(scores, alice):
    nscores = list(set(scores))
    for i in range(0,len(alice)):
        nscores.append(alice[i])
        print(nscores.index(alice[i])+1)
    nscores.sort(reverse = True)
```

Comment: the thing is everytime i run the code i don't wan to alter values of lists elements i want the initial lists and then append the single value.

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning any value from your `climbingLeaderboard` function...
Try the following:

```py
def climbingLeaderboard(scores, alice):
    # you need to move this out of your for loop,
    # otherwise you create a new one at each 
    # iteration
    nscores = list(set(scores))

    for i in range(0,len(alice)):
        nscores.append(alice[i])
        print(nscores.index(alice[i])+1)


    # you need to this only once
    nscores.sort(reverse = True)

    # and you need to return!
    return nscores
```

Comment: there is a reason i reinitialized nscores. because i don't wan to alter values of lists elements i want the initial lists and then append the single value and sort for that accordingly.

Comment: Okay, then you might consider providing us with an example input of scores and an expected output. Right now @blhsing and my answer seem the most probable expected output. Check out what is a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to get *real* help.